# Php, Regex, Between strings

Tags: php, regex

I was trying to find a pattern for the following scenario:

Lets say i have this string:

> someString[code]some code[/code]someString

Now **some code** can be anything, What i want to get is reserved words (break, class, etc), So for a real scenario this is a string:

```
someString
[code]
class someClass{}
[/code]
someString

// And again

someString
[code]
class someClass{}
[/code]
someString
```

So what i was trying to understand is how can i match all the reserved words that between all of the **[code][/code]** tags.

For example: `[code]someReservedWord some text anotherReservedWord[/code]` **I only want to match someReservedWord and anotherReservedWord**.

I was thinking to use **preg_match_all** So i can get all reserved words inside each [code][/code] and use **PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE** to get their positions,

The only thing i can't figure out is the pattern, if anyone got idea i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = <<<'LOD'
~ (?(DEFINE) (?<words> class | string | function ) )

(?: \[code] | \G(?<!^) )
(?: [^[]+? | \[(?!/code]) )*? \K
\b \g<words> \b

~x
LOD;

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

pattern details:

First at all we define a named group with all reserved words:

```
(?(DEFINE) (?<words> class | string | function ) )
```

The `(?(DEFINE)...)` syntax allows to define subpatterns out of the pattern itself. You can call the named group "words" later in the pattern with `\g<words>`.

`(?: [^[]+? | \[(?!/code]) )*?` describes all the content before a reserved word. This subpattern can match all except the closing tag `[/code]` because you have the choice between "all that is not a [" or "a [ not followed by `/code`". Since it can match all, lazy quantifiers are used to stop the match when a reserved word is encountered.

The entry point of the pattern is `(?: \[code] | \G(?<!^) )`. This enforce the match to begin with a `[code]` tag or to be contiguous to a precedent match.

(*`\G` is an anchor that means: "at the start of the string or contiguous to a precedent match". With the negative lookbehind `(?<!^)`, you forbid the start of the string*.)

`\K` is a trick that resets all the matched content before it from the match result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "someString[code]some code[/code]someString";
$ret = preg_replace('#\[code\](.+)\[\/code\]#iUs', '<FOUND>$1</FOUND>', $str);
var_dump($ret);
```

(http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2tD , see preg_match_all example)

You'll might google for BB-Code PHP regex.

Comment: I don't want all characters only specific ones as class|break|this but not (.+)